# Is it possible to include Javac lint in the Android lint report?

Tags: java, android, gradle

When generating the Android lint report using `./gradlew lintDebug`, the javac lint errors such as deprecation or unchecked conversions are not included in the report.

I currently am just enabling these javac options when compiling:

```
(build.gradle)
tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

But the problem with this is that the error messages are sent to the console, not to the lint report.

It is really a trivial matter, but it would be nice if all lint showed up in the same place.

My current lintDebug output:

```
$ ./gradlew lintDebug
:<Project Name>:preBuild
:<Project Name>:preDebugBuild
:<Project Name>:checkDebugManifest
:<Project Name>:preReleaseBuild
:<Project Name>:prepareFrAvianeyFacebookAndroidApi370Library
:<Project Name>:prepareDebugDependencies
:<Project Name>:compileDebugAidl
:<Project Name>:compileDebugRenderscript
:<Project Name>:generateDebugBuildConfig
:<Project Name>:mergeDebugAssets
:<Project Name>:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:<Project Name>:generateDebugResources
:<Project Name>:mergeDebugResources
:<Project Name>:processDebugManifest
:<Project Name>:processDebugResources
:<Project Name>:generateDebugSources
:<Project Name>:compileDebugJava
/path/to/some/File.java:136: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
                Iterator<String> keyIterator = errors.keys();
                                                          ^
  required: Iterator<String>
  found:    Iterator
1 warning
:<Project Name>:compileLint
:<Project Name>:lintDebug
Wrote HTML report to file:/path/to/lint-results-debug.html
Wrote XML report to /path/to/lint-results-debug.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.936 secs
```

And my lint-results-debug.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<issues format="4" by="lint 22.6.1">
     <issue id="IconDensities" /> <!-- Along with the information about the IconDensities lint -->
</issues>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment.

Once the Android plugin is compatible with the Java plugin you'll be able to run other static analysis tools that provides a Gradle plugin (findbugs, pmd, etc...). It'll be in their own report though.